# React Native types of functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and really confused on how to tell if its a function or class. From what I know, capital letter means a class?

Please let me know what each of the following are and their differences:

1. ```
   const location = props => (...)
   ```
2. ```
   const Location() => {}
   ```
3. ```
   function EventDetailScreen(props)
   ```
4. ```
   handleOnPressEvent = event => {...}
   ```
5. ```
   handleOnPressEvent = (event) => {...}
   ```

All of these really confuse me. I know what `const` means but #1 has props without the brackets (ex.`= ( props ) =>` )

#2 has capital 'L'
#3 begins with a `function` but then capital 'E'
#4 and #5 one with parentheses and other without.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a quick overview, but you'll need to look at some documentation or tutorials for more in depth explanations of everything.

In terms of capital letters or not, javascript (which is the scripting language you are writing for React Native in) does not care whether you use uppercase, lowercase, camelCase, PascalCase, etc. Now, it is case sensitive, so once you name something you need to match the case (*funcName* does not reference *FuncName* for example). There are common conventions when it comes to what case to use in naming something, but not really any rules. Check out this for some ideas of common convention (https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#naming).

Moving on to functions. Firstly, you ask about functions vs class, but just so you know none of those examples are classes. (We'll ignore how classes are just fancy functions in js since it's not relevant in this context).

What you have in your examples is a mix of two types of functions. You have [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) (which are your 'normal' functions) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

An arrow function is a special, compact form of a function expression. They are very compact and great for many - but not all - things. Check out [resources like this one](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc) to fully understand the differences.

Finally, to answer your specific questions:

1. This is an arrow function. Arrow functions with only a single argument do not need the braces. You do need the braces if you have zero props, or more than one arg. So `= () =>` and `= props =>` and `= (props) =>` and `= (props, others) =>` all work, but `= =>` `= props, others =>` would not be valid.
2. So the case of the L in this example doesn't really make a difference, it's only a matter of convention. However, it would not be valid because it doesn't have the `function` nor the first = of an arrow function. To be correct it would either be `const Location = () => {}` or `function Location = () => {}` (as a regular function) or `const Location = function locationFunction() {}` (but in this case maybe an arrow function is less verbose).
3. This is a normal function expression. Capitalization is a matter of convention.
4. Another arrow function. No parenthesis because it only has a single argument, so parenthesis are optional.
5. This is another arrow function. Parenthesis are included here but not necessary since there is only one arg.

Note that the curly braces are used in these examples after the function declaration to hold the body of the function. This is correct, but an arrow function CAN omit the curly braces IF it is running a single command or immediately returning something on the SAME line as the declaration.

For example: `handleOnPressEvent = event => console.log(event)` would not require the curly braces. Or `twoPlus = (num) => 2 + num;` which would be the same as

```
twoPlus= (num) => {
 return 2 + num;
}
```

Hope that clears it up a bit. There are other differences between arrow functions and regular functions ( and more between functions and classes ) so I recommend you look into those specifically a bit more.

Cheers